# How to prevent AS3 from automatically adding a line break?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have an issue with a specific string variable. It is automatically adding a line break after the text in the string characterName. On this frame I have a input text box with an instance name of name_Input and a submit button that executes the following code.

```
   var characterName:String;
   characterName = name_Input.text;
   //The next line was a solution I tried for this problem but it doesn't work
   characterName = characterName.split("\r\n").join("");
   nextFrame();
```

And on the next frame there is a trace to see what the value of that plus another variable is.

```
   trace(characterName+", the "+characterClass);
```

characterClass is automatically defined as "Default" so I can see if it worked properly.
The trace is displaying the following:

```
   "Name
   , the Default"
```

If anyone can help me figure out why the line break keeps showing up and how to prevent this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Also, if I hit the delete key before typing "Name" in the text box, it displays in line. So clearly the box has a line break in it automatically. I've already tried deleting and remaking the text box to make sure I hadn't accidentally added something to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Text Field is Single Line and not Multi Line in it's properties.

If that doesn't work, you can also try something like:
yourstring.replace(String.fromCharCode(13), "")

Comment: Documenation on [`TextField.multiline`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#multiline)

Comment: this worked. I thought I had fixed that before, but I guess it always helps to double check!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried separating the end-line and the carriage return?

```
characterName = characterName.split("\n").join("");
characterName = characterName.split("\r").join("");
```